# Webpack SASS in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: webpack, sass, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get my first ASP.Net Core 2 project to include SASS files. I think this issue is only happening with the SASS files. CSS files seem to be working properly. I've tried a number of different approaches/loaders and followed examples online. The only one that doesn't cause errors is the following, however please see my 'side note' at the bottom of this question:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'] }
```

If I use Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the SASS file was included and the @imports that it contains have also been included.

[image: DevTools]

But the styles aren't being applied.

For example, main-client.js contains:

```
 html {\n  position: relative;\n  min-height: 100%;\n  background: #ffffff; }
```

But when I look at the applied styles, min-height is not set. I also can't find the styles being inserted into the inline style tags in the header.

[image: min-height missing]

These are my current webpack files.

**webpack.config.vendor.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/flex-layout',
    '@angular/material',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['ClientApp/dist']),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['wwwroot/dist']),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;


module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|woff|eot|woff2)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

Thank you for reading through this large question and thanks for the help in advance! Been at this for about a month and not got anywhere.

Side note: I've tried a number of different loaders such as `style-loader`. I've also tried using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, however I get errors such as `Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings` or `Module build failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I assume the 2nd one is that the asp.net prerendering is unable to run due to the fact it's not a browser, but I couldn't figure out how to get around that.

Comment: I'm issuing the exact same problem here. Does anyone know a way around his?